# How to set TCP Packet Rate in Simulation

Tags: tcp, tcpclient, ns2

In NS2 how can one set the packet  rate of source .Please share the parameter and how can I set, I know how to set UDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike UDP-based CBR (Constant Bit-rate), TCP applications are not rate-based. The underlying TCP layer would send the data as per the congestion control mechanisms (slow-start, congestion-avoidance, and fast-recovery). Thus, the user cannot dictate the sending rate in TCP. That is why, it is likely that you would not find an NS command to set the rate of a TCP application like ftp.